# Center the wrapper on a horizontal website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website that is horizantal with a total width of 12500px, it's build in 5 pages.

http://70.33.241.140/~flori281/website/

The problem is that i don't know how i can center the wrapper? Because there are a lot of different screenwidth. Is there a way to let the div ".box" automaticly scale to screenwidth?

Answer (score 0):

Centering horizontally via CSS is done using the `auto` setting for the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties:

```
.centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i now that but that's not the problem. Because the container is 12500px width. The div .box have to scale to fullscreen (not 12500px) and in this div the div "wrapper" has to center

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper holder div css is

```
.box {
    float: left;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 2400px;
}
```

It has 2400px width, so that is the reason you wont see it as center, but it is centered.

Comment: Yes i know, this width has to be the fullscreen width (not the full container width) Do you know a script or a other idea how the width can be automaticly be set?

Comment: @Geppie So you can use 100% without PX value.

Comment: @ Sameera Thilakasiri : If i do that the width of .box1 is going to be the full width of the container, this is 12500px. And that's not good

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to change some stuff in your css:

```
#content{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.box{
    line-height:22px;
}
```

Now I understand what you're trying to do. In that case you're gonna have to use javascript. But leave the CSS like the example I'm giving so it will look good when it's loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var actualContentWidth = $("#content").width();
    var boxes = $("#content .box").length;
    var newWidth = boxes * actualContentWidth;
    newWidth += "px";
    $("#content").css({width:newWidth });
    $("#content .box").css({width:actualContentWidth + "px",float:'left'});
});
```

If you want it to resize when the window resizes:

```
function reCalculateSizes(){
    $("#content").css({width:"100%"});
    var actualContentWidth = $("#content").width();
    var boxes = $("#content .box").length;
    var newWidth = boxes * actualContentWidth;
    newWidth += "px";
    $("#content").css({width:newWidth });
    $("#content .box").css({width:actualContentWidth + "px",float:'left'});
}
$(document).ready(reCalculateSizes);
$(window).resize(reCalculateSizes);
```

Comment: Hi, i changed this but it won't work. The container has to be 12500px width otherwise the different pages won't work. So this container has 5 pages called div.box, in this div.box is the div.wrapper that has to center. Hope you can follow it :D

Comment: So i changed #content to #container and put your code in. The wrapper is perfect centered in on every window. The thing is that the pages are now vertical and not horizontal anymore. Als the scaling of the background-image is not good anymore.

Comment: My mistake, there was a double dot on the last line of the js, copy the js now.

Comment: Also, change the div id back to content on the HTML

Comment: So i changed in the HTML container to content and put the new code in. Still it's not working correctly. You know what it can be? I'm working on it for 3 day's now and it's pissing me of :D Thanks for your help mate

Comment: Update with latest javascript, I just tested on your page and it works!

Comment: It works..! every box is a div as well. I put position:absolute; to every div and also put a margin to every box. Thank you su much, you are a thrue hero ;) Is it also possible when resizing the window it automaticly calculate a new width? Cheers

Comment: Oh, and if worked please don't forget to mark my answer as the best answer :)